# Thread safety of Vector of atomic bool

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

If I have a vector:

```cpp
std::vector<std::atomic_bool> v(8);
```

and **assuming I won't modify its size post creation**, is it thread safe to call:

```cpp
bool result = v[2].compare_exchange_strong(false, true);
```

<sub>* the values 8, 2, false and true are just given as an example use case.</sub>

Comment: Depends on your goals. `v[2]` could be changed immediately after reading and before you can make use of `result`.

Comment: Yes, it is safe to call this function (as in - the effects are well-defined). However, it is somewhat likely that you need a loop and compare_exchange_weak.

Comment: @user4581301 that would be true even for a stand-alone `std::atomic_bool`, right?

Comment: @user4581301 The result holds whether the CAS operation succeeded, not the value of v[2]

Comment: My apologies, but the result is the same. The *function* is safe, but your usage of it might not.

Comment: @SergeyA hm then it all depends on whether I'll be causing a cache ping pong and would be better off locking and unlocking a vector of simple bool.

Comment: @LorahAttkins I do not really know your use case, but in many application of CAS you want to repeat the operation until it succeeds rather than try it once. Hence my comment. It could well be that your use case is not like that.

Comment: @SergeyA spot on, I'd check in a loop until I find an empty slot (`v[i] == false` -> `make true and select i`). When all slots fail, I wait on a condition variable and run the loop again. The cv is triggered when someone frees a slot (`make v[i] false again`)

Comment: The code shown is fine from the stand point of race conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP appears to be asking whether multiple threads can evaluate

```
v[2].compare_exchange_strong(false, true)
```

when such evaluations are potentially concurrent, without causing a data race.

This will not compile because `compare_exchange_strong` requires an lvalue as its first argument. I will assume that this issue is corrected.

The answer is yes. According to [container.requirements.dataraces]/1:

> For purposes of avoiding data races (16.5.5.10), implementations shall consider the following functions to be `const`: `begin`, `end`, `rbegin`, `rend`, `front`, `back`, `data`, `find`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, `equal_range`, `at` and, except in associative or unordered associative containers, `operator[]`.

This implies that evaluating `v[2]` is not allowed to modify the vector (nor any internal static data that might be shared between threads) and thus may not race with the same evaluation in another thread. The `compare_exchange_strong` operation is being performed on an atomic object, so it's impossible for it to race with anything.

Comment: +1 Even though I have a note mentioning that the values 8, 2, false and true are just an example. This [demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51ef62df4db5762a) is equivalent. Thanks for ping pointing that it all boils down to `operator[]` being `const` and the related quote.